# Android Emulator: failed to initialize WHPX

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to get the Android Emulator to work on my Ryzen CPU, but I keep getting the error:

```
Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64.exe: WHPX: Failed to enable partition extended X64MsrExit and X64CpuidExit hr=80070057
Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64.exe: failed to initialize WHPX: Invalid argument.
```

I have enabled both Hyper V and Windows Hypervisor. I've also made sure my BIOS settings are correct, and virtualization is shown as enabled in task manager.
I could really use some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when emulating a Nexus5X. After deleting the device and re-creating it with Pie x86 it worked fine. Make sure to check the following:

- activate Visualization in your BIOS (SVM Mode)
- Android Studio and Emulator are up-to-date
- Windows Hypervisor and Hyper-V-Hypervisor in Windows Features are activated (uncheck Hyper-V-Services)
- run Android Studio as Administrator

Answer (score 0):

Try to open Android Studio with Administrator rights.